# Laravel 5.4 where to write javascript code?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm really sorry for an absolutely stupid question but I don't understand where I should write js code in Laravel 5.4.
My site will consist of 2 parts, one for users `app` and other one for admin `dashboard`, and every part will have its own js and css files, so it's my `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/dashboard.js', 'public/js/dashboard.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/dashboard.css')
   .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css/app.css');
```

Files
`resources/assets/js/dashboard.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

`resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Where do I write my own code?

Comment: What do you want to code? Own Vue Components? VanillaJS? jQuery?

Comment: I don't know what is Vue, I've never used it. I want to add jQuery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app.js` or `dashboard.js` files in your `resources/assets/js/` folder are normal JS files. So you can add your code directly there, e.g.:

**dashboard.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    ///Your code here
});
```

But don't forget to include the js files in your public folder to your HTML file.

If you don't want to use VueJS in your project you can remove it entirely.

**dashboard.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function() {
    ///Your code here
});
```

Comment: I removed all code from `resources/assets/js/dashboard.js` and added `$(document).ready(function() { alert(1);});` to it and then `npm run dev`, but after it nothing happened, code doesn't work and `dashboard.js` contains a lot of other code, but not mine.

Comment: The additional code comes from the bootstrap file which you require. Do you add the dashboard js file to your HTML code like this: `<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>` ?

Comment: It looks like I have a problem with caching, after I updated the files using the F5, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 files for example:
`admin.js` and `front.js`. Than compile it in `public/js` directory as separate js files:

```
mix.webpack('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js/admin.js')
.webpack('resources/assets/js/front.js', 'public/js/front.js')
```

and use it separately in the layouts.

In your `admin.js` file example:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('./jquery-3.1.1.js');
require('./bootstrap');
require('./bootstrap-tagsinput');
require('./bootstrap-progressbar');
require('./custom.js');
require('./jquery.nestable.js');
require('./canvas-to-blob');
require('./purify');
require('./bordercoloranimate');
window.sweetAlert = require('./sweetalert.min.js');
```